# Create buffer in meters

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm trying to create a buffer around a feature in a polygon in QGIS. Trying to do 100m buffer, but when I run it, I just get a huge circle around what my shapefile was showing originally.

I have tried changing CRSs on the layer, and the project a million times. I always try to find one that uses meters (`+vunits=m` right?). I've saved the layer and opened it fresh to make sure the project  had the same CRS and it keeps doing the same thing. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you edited your question and detailed exactly what the original CRS of the layer is and what you did to change it.

Comment: If that feature is point than buffer will be a circle

Comment: Vunits mean vertical units, you are interested in horizontal ones. I would test by converting data to some UTM zone physically, not on-the-fly.

Comment: @user30184 How do I do that?

Comment: @nagib The shapefile has both polygons and lines.

Comment: @Luke It was EPSG:4269 originally, and I changed it to EPSG:26910

Comment: I solved it with the MMQGIS Plugin